# Google ecommerce Datalayer

Tags: javascript, arrays, e-commerce, google-datalayer

Does anyone know how google gets information from datalayer array? I mean, does google get the datalayer everytime when the array is modified, or maybe he gets it when the page is going to be closed, or even it gets, for example, every n seconds?
Thanks!

Comment: just google it: https://www.optimizesmart.com/google-tag-manager-data-layer-explained-like-never/

Comment: I did already and found that site also, but there's no answer for my question :(